# Postgres : Select columns based on row values

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 tables:

*Table A*

```
 Section | measure_name   |
---------+----------------|
 A       |      col1      |
 B       |      col2      |
 C       |      col3      |
```

*Table B*

```
 Facility | col1| col2| col3| 
----------+-----+-----+-----+
 NY       |  5  | 50  |  90 |
```

I want to write a query which selects `measure_name` of `Table A` from `Table B`.

Comment: Can you show the desired results based on the sample data you've posted?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you want to get the the values from Table B for the columns corresponding to each  `measure_name`

If yes, you use `UNNEST()` to convert the Table B into rows and then join it with table A.

```
with c AS
( SELECT 
       unnest(array['col1', 'col2', 'col3']) AS colname,
       unnest(array[col1, col2, col3]) AS value
FROM B
) 
SELECT a.*,c.value FROM A 
JOIN C ON a.measure_name = c.colname;
```

This gives you

```
Section measure_name value
A       col1          5
B       col2         50
C       col3         90
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=36f2b4918e8ead5582241b62e42279f4)